# How to attach my public key of a digitally signed PDF using Python?

Tags: python, encryption, hash, rsa, digital-signature

From what I understand from hours of googling. We hash the PDF and encrypt it using a RSA algorithm with a public and private key generation. We then share the PDF along with the public key.

Then When verifying the signature,the receiver has to hash the pdf data and then decrypt the encryption using the public key and check whether both values are same to verify the signature.

Now how the public key and the encrypted data using private key is attached to the pdf?
Also when receiving we should know the hash function used and the algorithm used to encrypt the data to verify the signature Right? How all of this is achieved.